# Test can only be run as active user

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write a test class for my Apex trigger, and I am setting up a user in the following way:

```
User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE profileId IN (SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator') AND isActive = TRUE LIMIT 1];

    System.RunAs(u1) 
    { ...}
```

When I run my test, I always get the following error message:

```
System.TypeException: System.runAs can only be used with an active user
```

I don't understand as my user is set to active...

Tia
Reena

Comment: This doesn't make sense, are you sure your changes were saved (assuming you are using an IDE). Sometimes the IDE (Eclipse or Mavensmate) report that the change but it doesn't actually save the new code. Have you verified by viewing the test from Salesforce?

Comment: yes, it was saved. i always thought that in apex things were case insensitive, but I tried it out anyway, and changed TRUE to true and now it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than have dependencies on your current user records (which cause problems like this) in your tests, it is usually beneficial to actually create test users as part of your test, during the initialisation. Like this....

```
static testmethod void myProfileSpecificTest()
{
    // Let's create a new test user
    Profile testProfile = [SELECT Id 
                           FROM profile
                           WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' 
                           LIMIT 1];

    User testUser = new User(LastName = 'test user 1', 
                             Username = 'test.user.1@example.com', 
                             Email = 'test.1@example.com', 
                             Alias = 'testu1', 
                             TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT', 
                             LocaleSidKey = 'en_GB', 
                             EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', 
                             ProfileId = testProfile.Id, 
                             LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US');     

    Test.startTest();
        System.runas(testUser)
        {
            .....Do Some Testing...
        }
    Test.stopTest();

    ..... assert the results are correct .....
}
```

You don't even have to insert the new user in the test, and any new users you create as part of your test are always guaranteed to be active, plus are free from any licence restrictions.

Further details and examples can be found at: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I am now able to answer the question myself. The solution was as simple as changing the code to:

```
User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE profileId IN (SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator') AND isActive = true LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: What change was made? That looks like the same code you have in your question.

Comment: I see the change now. `TRUE` was changed to `true`

Comment: I have a hard time believing this is the solution, since I use `TRUE` and `true` interchangeably. So now, if you change `TRUE` back to `true`, is it broken again?